# Represent a field as a custom object (Mail::Address for example)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to do this:

```
e = Email.new
e.from = Mail::Address.new "ABC <a@a.com>"
e.from.class # => String
```

As you can see the `from` gets converted from `Mail::Address` to `String`.

It's possible to keep the object when assigning a value to an ActiveRecord object's field?

What alternatives do I have?

Comment: I tested your code and I get "Mail::Address", not "String". I do get "String" if I define the `from=` metod to assign a string. Have you explicitly defined the `from=`method? Or are you just using `attr_accessor :from`?

Comment: No. Rails 4.2.5.2. There is no settings on the Email model. What rails version are you using?

Comment: I’m using Rails 5.1.4.